# DRF : parameter in custom permission class with function based views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build my API and it works fine.
I use [function based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views) to manage my endpoints.
It works well too but I'm trying to add a [custom permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) and putting parameters with it do not work.

An example of one of my endpoints :

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=["GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def team_kanban(request):
    """
    List all Helpdesk Teams with kanban fields.
    """
    teams = HelpdeskTeam.objects.all()
    return Response(HelpdeskTeamKanbanSerializer(teams, many=True).data)
```

It works without any problem.
But when I try to do :

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=["GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, HasPermission("view_helpdeskteam")])
def team_kanban(request):
    """
    List all Helpdesk Teams with kanban fields.
    """
    teams = HelpdeskTeam.objects.all()
    return Response(HelpdeskTeamKanbanSerializer(teams, many=True).data)
```

with this custom permission class :

```py
from rest_framework import permissions


class HasPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to users who have the appropriate permission.
    """

    permission_codename = ""

    def __init__(self, permission_codename):
        super().__init__()
        self.permission_codename = permission_codename

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_permission(self.permission_codename)
```

It doesn't work.
The full error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 415, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 331, in check_permissions
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 278, in get_permissions
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]    
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 278, in <listcomp>
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]    
TypeError: 'HasPermission' object is not callable
```

It seems my class is not callable with the parameter.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`permission_classes` must be passed a list of permission classes, not instances of permissions. One way to dynamically create permission classes would be to create a method that returns a dynamically created class using `type`

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class HasPermissionBase(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to users who have the appropriate permission.
    """

    permission_codename = ""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_permission(self.permission_codename)


def HasPermission(permission_codename):
    return type('HasPermission', (HasPermissionBase, ), {'permission_codename': permission_codename})
```

Or you could override the `__call__` method on your custom permission and return `self` so that it acts like a class when called

```
class HasPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to users who have the appropriate permission.
    """

    permission_codename = ""

    def __init__(self, permission_codename):
        super().__init__()
        self.permission_codename = permission_codename

    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_permission(self.permission_codename)
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks ! Overriding `__call__` did the trick ! I did read things about that but didn't know how to turn it.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perfect explanation, but has a wrong information. When you override the __call__ method the class acts like a function, not like a class. After all, the class already act like a class!